# Impact of setting -XX:+DisableExplicitGC when NIO direct buffers are used

Tags: java, garbage-collection, nio

We are building a web application with aggressive performance SLAs which are periodically being violated due to the JVM going out to lunch due to System.gc() calls. We've done some debugging, and determined that in all cases it's the internal app server code which is invoking System.gc(). This occurs a few times while the app server is booting or the application is deployed, which we aren't concerned about. However, System.gc() is also periodically be triggered when the app is up and running via internal app server calls the NIO classes. Here's a stack trace we were able to capture of this event:

```
3XMTHREADINFO      "WebContainer : 25" J9VMThread:0x0000000006FC5D00, j9thread_t:0x00007F60E41753E0, java/lang/Thread:0x000000060B735590, state:R, prio=5
3XMJAVALTHREAD            (java/lang/Thread getId:0xFE, isDaemon:true)
3XMTHREADINFO1            (native thread ID:0x1039, native priority:0x5, native policy:UNKNOWN)
3XMTHREADINFO2            (native stack address range from:0x00007F6067621000, to:0x00007F6067662000, size:0x41000)
3XMCPUTIME               CPU usage total: 80.222215853 secs
3XMHEAPALLOC             Heap bytes allocated since last GC cycle=1594568 (0x1854C8)
3XMTHREADINFO3           Java callstack:
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/lang/System.gc(System.java:329)
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/nio/Bits.syncReserveMemory(Bits.java:721)
5XESTACKTRACE                   (entered lock: java/nio/Bits@0x000000060000B690, entry count: 1)
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/nio/Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:766(Compiled Code))
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/nio/DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123(Compiled Code))
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/nio/ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:306(Compiled Code))
4XESTACKTRACE                at com/ibm/ws/buffermgmt/impl/WsByteBufferPoolManagerImpl.allocateBufferDirect(WsByteBufferPoolManagerImpl.java:706(Compiled Code))
4XESTACKTRACE                at com/ibm/ws/buffermgmt/impl/WsByteBufferPoolManagerImpl.allocateCommon(WsByteBufferPoolManagerImpl.java:612(Compiled Code))
4XESTACKTRACE                at com/ibm/ws/buffermgmt/impl/WsByteBufferPoolManagerImpl.allocateDirect(WsByteBufferPoolManagerImpl.java:527(Compiled Code))
4XESTACKTRACE                at com/ibm/io/async/ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:507(Compiled Code))
4XESTACKTRACE                at com/ibm/io/async/ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905(Compiled Code))
4XESTACKTRACE                at com/ibm/ws/util/ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864(Compiled Code))
3XMTHREADINFO3           Native callstack:
4XENATIVESTACK               (0x00007F61083DD122 [libj9prt26.so+0x13122])
4XENATIVESTACK               (0x00007F61083EA79F [libj9prt26.so+0x2079f])
....
```

Is anyone aware of what the impact would be if we shut down the calls to System.gc() by enabling -XX:+DisableExplicitGC (or actually in our case by setting -Xdisableexplicitgc since we're running Websphere on the IBM JRE, which does the same thing)? We certainly don't want to create a memory leak. I haven't been able to find a direct reference as to why the System.gc() calls in NIO are actually necessary, and there isn't a code comment specifically addressing it where it occurs in JDK code, either: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/4a1e42601d61/src/share/classes/java/nio/Bits.java

If it's a bad idea to completely disable System.gc() due to the use of NIO, is there at least something we can do to reduce the frequency at which it's called? It appears that we can set -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize, but this appears as if it would only set up upper bound on the amount of allocated memory, and would just as likely have an adverse affect.

Comment: which GC are you using?

Comment: We're using the gencon GC policy on the IBM JVM. (If you're not familiar with the peculiarities of the IBM JVM, the gencon policy is very similar to the CMS collector on Hotspot.)

Comment: in that case making sure that the concurrent cycle runs often enough so that buffers which are eligible for GC can be reclaimed might also do the job

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling explicit GCs does not prevent buffers and thus the native memory they hold onto from being collected. But it may delay collections for a long time.

Which means memory allocated by direct buffers may accumulate for a long time before it is collected. In the long run that's not really a leak, but it will increase peak memory usage.

> http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/4a1e42601d61/src/share/classes/java/nio/Bits.java

As I understand it that `System.gc()` call is there to free buffers when the `reserveMemory` limit is hit. After reserving the requested amount `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect` will call to `Unsafe.allocateMemory` which might do its own GC call, which should not be affected by `DisableExplicitGC`, if its attempt to mmap fails.

> is there at least something we can do to reduce the frequency at which it's called?

It is only called when the `MaxDirectMemorySize` limitation is hit. If you can tune your GC or application code so that it meets one of the following options:

- it uses a fixed set of buffers (-> limitation will never be exceeded)
- buffers are collected early (shortlived buffers -> die in a young GC)
- the old generation gets collected regularly before direct buffer space runs out
- uses heap buffers instead of direct buffers

then `System.gc()` calls won't be necessary.

On hotspot there also exists a `ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent` option. Maybe IBM's VM has something similar.

Comment: Thanks very much! Can we also increase the setting for -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize to delay when we would hit this limit and System.gc() would be called?

Looking at the v7 of OpenJDK, it looks like an OOM Error is thrown if there isn't enough direct memory free under the MaxDirectMemorySize threshold: [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/nio/Bits.java#Bits.0reservedMemory). Given that, I guess it would be a bad idea to disable System.gc() altogether but instead should use the GC tuning techniques you suggested above to delay or avoid it.

Comment: yes you can do that, but I didn't cover that option since you already mentioned it yourself.